# how to blur parent view, while leaving subview unblurred

Tags: swift, uikit

[image]I need to implement a pop up feature like in the photo below. I am able to make the background of the pop up different from my superview, but when I try to make the superview alpha to 0.5, and the pop up alpha 1.0, I am still seeing the pop up faded like the superview.

How can I achieve this? In IB the pop up view is a subview of my main view controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create additional view that is a child of the superview you are trying to blur. If you change alpha of parent, all subviews are also affected. This is why you create this additional view and change the alpha component on it.

Comment: I created the view in storyboards, and set the alpha to 1.0. However in the view hierarchy its a subview, I cannot drag it out. Should I create it via code?

Comment: I mean you can create programmatically, but it not necessary. Try to pull it above the superview in the tree.